# How do I open Excel Application using xlrd or xlwt?

Tags: python, excel, win32com, xlrd, xlwt

I know I can open MS Excel application using win32com by setting Visible to true
Can I use xlrd or xlwt do the same?

Comment: xlrd is for reading excel formatted spreadsheets. I dont think you can open excel application

Comment: Yes, neither of these programs has any connection to Excel, and it would be kind of silly for them to have built-in functionality to open Excel considering they don't even require it to be installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xlrd and xlwt are both libraries for reading Excel's files (that is, the storage format) - they have no connection to the actual Excel executable or libraries (they don't even require that Excel is installable on the system in question (I'm using them, for example on a CentOS machine).

If you simply want to lauch Excel you can use [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess):

```
# Note, your path probably differs
subprocess.call(r"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.exe")

# The script will wait until Excel is closed and then continue
```